# Carthage prevents Xcode 9.2 from building

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage, quick-nimble, nimble

I have been experimenting on a project with using Carthage.
Having installed Carthage I then attempted to add Nimble and Quick to the project through Carthage.

However, I get the following on carthage update:

`user$ carthage update
*** Fetching Quick
*** Fetching Nimble
*** Checking out Nimble at "v5.1.1"
*** Checking out Quick at "v1.2.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/g_/h57q7zyj569cgs2rryp8cmk40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.YUIvqk.log
*** Building scheme "Nimble-iOS" in Nimble.xcodeproj
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/user/nbrownapp/Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble/Nimble.xcodeproj -scheme Nimble-iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/user/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.2_9C40b/Nimble/v5.1.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/g_/h57q7zyj569cgs2rryp8cmk40000gp/T/Nimble SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO (launched in /Users/user/nbrownapp/Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble)`

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: `/var/folders/g_/h57q7zyj569cgs2rryp8cmk40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.YUIvqk.log`

The project itself fails to build with numerous Shell Script Invocation Errors. Uninstalling Carthage, removing the Cartfile, Cartfile.resolved and the Carthage folder from the project and deleting the script leads to the project building without any errors. However, I would like to use Carthage and can't see why I can't get it to build the dependencies? Or why the project won't build when Carthage is installed?

If I remove the above and try again I get the same error.

I've been following the Ray Wenderlich example:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/165660/carthage-tutorial-getting-started-2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try running the `carthage` command with the `--verbose` argument and update the logs above?

Comment: @BojanDimovski --verbose 
just tells you what system/cmd is doing and what drivers and software it is loading during startup or in programming it would produce detailed output for diagnostic purposes thus makes a program easier to debug BUT above problem will persist.